# Get x, y, width and height of images on main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm struggling with what I'm sure is a simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out or find a similar issue!

I have an animation in Adobe Animate which consists of a bunch of images on different layers on each frame. I am re-creating the animation in JavaScript so I've created a spritesheet of the images in Photoshop, and now I want to record the positions and sizes of each of them in Animate. There are 30 layers and 280 frames, so it's a LOT of images! All I want to do is trace out the x and y positions of each image along with their width and height each time I enter a frame.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var doc = MovieClip(root);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    trace("--------------");
    trace(doc);
    trace("frame: " + doc.currentFrame);
    for (var i:uint=0; i < doc.numChildren; i++) {
        var child = doc.getChildAt(i);
        if (child !== null){
            trace(child);
            trace(child.x);
        }
    }
}
```

but I get the same thing traced every frame, which is

```
--------------
[object MainTimeline]
frame: 2
[object Shape]
0
```

even when I have multiple layers each with images on, I get a single `[object shape]` shown in the Output window and its x position is always 0.

can anyone help shed any light please?

Comment: I don't see any problems with the **code**. My guess is that **doc** somehow doesn't refer the same timeline as the one with the frames and images. I'd just put the code on a separate layer of the same timeline and operated in the given context, to avoid the confusion.

Comment: It's quite possible that Adobe Animate just collapsed all the FLA's frames into a single Shape with a very complicated inset `graphics`. Try reading [`child.graphics.readGraphicsData(true)`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#readGraphicsData()) (obviously checking if there's a graphics in a child, but since you always get a Shape, there should be) for whether that graphics is actually a different one each frame. If yes, you have a flattened SWF but a means to export all the graphics as a bundle per frame.

Comment: @Vesper Needs checking. If I remember correctly Flash doesn't do it even with vector shapes, if you put them on distinct layers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vesper thanks for the pointer, using `child.graphics.readGraphicsData(true)`, I managed to get the x and y positions of each image on the stage. I've also realised that I don't actually need the width and height, since I can grab these from the spritesheet I made. So my working code is:

```
var doc;
doc = MovieClip(root) as DisplayObjectContainer;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    for (var i:uint=0; i < doc.numChildren; i++) {
        var child = doc.getChildAt(i);
        if (child !== null){
            var gElms = child.graphics.readGraphicsData(true);
            for (var g:uint=0; g < gElms.length; g++) {
                if (getQualifiedClassName(gElms[g]).indexOf("GraphicsBitmapFill") > -1){
                    trace("{frame: " + doc.currentFrame + ", x: " + gElms[g].matrix.tx + ", y: " + gElms[g].matrix.ty + "},");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which traces out something like

```
{frame: 2, x: 412, y: 312},
{frame: 3, x: 470, y: 126},
{frame: 4, x: 370, y: 255},
{frame: 5, x: 214, y: 91},
{frame: 6, x: 253, y: 392},
{frame: 7, x: 713, y: 120},
{frame: 8, x: 336, y: 386},
{frame: 9, x: 463, y: 287},
{frame: 10, x: 629, y: 362},
{frame: 11, x: 336, y: 411},
{frame: 12, x: 634, y: 283},
{frame: 13, x: 217, y: 237},
{frame: 14, x: 462, y: 322},
{frame: 15, x: 496, y: 331},
{frame: 16, x: 411, y: 312},
{frame: 17, x: 228, y: 297},
{frame: 18, x: 460, y: 191},
{frame: 19, x: 152, y: 118},
{frame: 20, x: 768, y: 203},
{frame: 21, x: 177, y: 289},
{frame: 22, x: 65, y: 45},
```

which I can copy-paste straight into JavaScript :o)

Thanks guys, your help is much appreciated.